# changes in ~/.mc/ini dont take effect

Tags: linux, bash, unix, prompt, ini

I am trying to customize a shell. I have added this into `.bash_profile`:

```
HOST="Host"
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\e]0;$USER@$HOST: $(pwd -P)\a"'
```

The command prompt was changed, but when I run `mc` again, it changes my prompt.

I've changed `[Layout] => command_prompt` to `0` in `~/.mc/ini` file but it gets back to `1` when I restart mc.

I have already tried to set 444 for `~/.mc/ini` but it was useless.

Comment: Why not just unselect Options -> Layout -> Command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you edit `~/.mc/ini` file (or `~/.config/mc/ini` in newer versions), it is important to not edit it from within `mc` itself (using `mcedit`).

If you quit from all instances of `mc` and edit this `ini` file using any other editor - `nano`, `gedit`, etc, this will work as you expect.

Reason why it is happening is because on exit `mc` will overwrite `ini` with current configuration, and your changes are lost.

Comment: Closed as *off topic* and still so *on topic* for the last 20 minutes for me. Thank you very much for this answer. I was pulling my hair out why everything was back to default once I left `mcedit` :-) +1

Comment: To add to the original answer: any other instance of `mc` that is running at the moment will overwrite `mc/ini` file on close. To be on the safe side, ensure that no `mc` are running when you do editing of ini file.